# Using PHP Superglobals correctly in a loop

Tags: php, foreach, warnings, superglobals

I'm trying to clean up some code and am getting a warning

"Do not Access Superglobal $_GET Array Directly"

on a loop that is used to collect what was returned.

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    $allinfo.= "_GET = $name : $value<br>";
}
```

Now is is nice and easy to do individual records so

```
$token = $_REQUEST['token'];
```

becomes

```
$token = filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'token');
```

but I'm slightly stuck on how to fix this for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    $allinfo.= "_GET = $name : " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, $name) . "<br>";
}
```

OR

```
foreach (filter_input_array(INPUT_GET) as $name => $value) {
    $allinfo.= "_GET = $name : $value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    $allinfo.= "_GET = $name : " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, $name) . "<br>";
}
```

I don't know if this is enough for your code validator (Netbeans I guess). You can also try:

```
foreach (array_keys($_GET) as $name) {
    $allinfo.= "_GET = $name : " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, $name) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes it is Netbeans and sadly those still show a warning under the first line where it says $_GET